# How do I get the ARN for a security group in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'd like to be able to query the ARN of a security group, but queries like `aws ec2 describe-security-groups` only provide group IDs.  Clearly security groups do have ARNs because API calls like `aws datasync create-agent` has [options](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/datasync/create-agent.html#options) that require security group ARNs.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

The ARN of security groups has **known format**:

```
arn:aws:ec2:<region>:<account>:security-group/<sg-group-id>
```

For example:

```
arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:123445667:security-group/sg-11223344551122334
```

Thus you can always construct it yourself if its not explicitly given by AWS CLI.

Comment: That seems like the best option available.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Marcin's answer works, but is a bit of a slow and potentially error prone process putting all that info together manually, especially if you have multiple to do.  I think Amazon should make it easier from the GUI, but in absence of that, you can use this quick method from the CLI:

Windows:

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources | findstr "sg-example1234567890"
```

Linux:

```
aws resourcegroupstaggingapi get-resources | grep "sg-example1234567890"
```

(Replacing **sg-example1234567890** with your actual security group.)

---

It's a bit of a clumsy way of doing it under the bonnet, there might be a more efficient way, in which case please suggest it, but for now this gets the job done and (in my experience at least) returns very quickly.